# How to conditionally select all elements of a data.frame that match a number of factors

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have to select a bunch of data from a data frame depending on certain conditions. The data frame looks roughly like this:

```
  F1 F2 D1 D2
1 A1 B1  1  0
2 A1 B1  1  1
3 A1 B1  0  0
4 A1 B2  1  0
5 A1 B2  0  0
6 A2 B2  1  0
7 A2 B2  1  1
```

The `Fx` are factors, and the `Dx` are data values. What I have to do is the following:

1. Find rows with data values that match a specific pattern.
2. For each row that matches that pattern, find all rows that have the same factors
3. For each unique factor combination, apply some operation to all rows that have that combination

For example,

```
factors <- unique(data[D1==1 & D2 == 1, c("F1","F2")])
```

will give me step 1 and most of 2.

And with

```
data[data$F1 %in% factors$F1 & data$F2 %in% factors%F2,]
```

I'm getting closer to the solution, but with the example data above, this will select all rows. But rows 4 and 5 should not be selected, because they are not an exact match. How can I add in some sort of condition that required that the %in% matches happen on the same row?

I feel like this is something that should be a common operation and thus R probably has a clever way for doing this.

Any ideas???? Thanks.

Comment: Get to know the `plyr` package - this will make most of your analysis quite easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the indexing of the `data.table` package to select all rows that have to be manipulated.

```
data <- data.table(data,key="F1,F2")
data[unique(data[D1 == 1 & D2 == 1,list(F1,F2)])]
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be replicating what I already have. But I'm but I'm not yet sure how to move from there. I guess the data.table documentation will help me there.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. This seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a job for `tapply` and `paste` ... for instance, let's define data2 as the same as your data object but with a "Val" column (you don't say what kind of row operation you might want to do, so this is just to help illustrate)...

```
  F1 F2 D1 D2 D3 D4 Val
1 A1 B1  1  1  0  1   7
2 A1 B1  1  0  1  1  19
3 A2 B1  1  1  1  1  43
```

Now check out the following command:

```
tapply(data2$Val,paste(data2$F1,data2$F2,sep="~"),sum)
```

You should get this output:

```
A1~B1 A2~B1 
   26    43
```

It should be clear that R is calculating the sum of Val for each possible combination of F1 and F2 (actually, as the command shows, it looks at the paste of F1 and F2 which amounts to the same thing)... for A1~B1 the sum is 26 (7 + 19) and for A2~B1 the sum is 43 (there's only one such row). Change `sum` to `length` in the tapply, and you'll get the number of such rows, and so on.

Hope this helps... :)

**EDIT**: Just saw your modification. If you're just after all the rows in data where the combination of F1 and F2 is one of the combinations of F1 and F2 listed in your factors object... you could just use `paste`:

```
data[paste(data$F1,data$F2,sep="~") %in% paste(factors$F1,factors$F2,sep="~"),]
```

The `sep="~"` isn't strictly needed, just force of habit. The above line should give you the rows you desire I think. If you want to execute a function on each subset of rows having a particular F1/F2 combination, use tapply as explained above :)

---

dput for data2 is below for convenience:

```
structure(list(
F1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), 
F2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "B1", class = "factor"), 
D1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), D2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), D3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), 
D4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Val = c(7, 19, 43)), 
.Names = c("F1", "F2", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "Val"), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Check out the "EDIT" part of my proposed solution first... it should hopefully solve your problem :)